# How to do Partial Checkout in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have three branches in my bitbucket Project repository-- `development, release and master`. The development branch contains a lot of development work from multiple teams.

So for Prod Migration I have to migrate few jobs from development to master and I have created a release branch from development branch. I know the checkout happens on a commit basis, but I don't want to have the entire development work in release branch.

I want release branch to have only production data and only this has to be merged with Master.

Please let me know if there is any solution on this or if there is any best practice strategy to follow while migrating the code from dev to prod.

Comment: Is a [`--depth 1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) what you're looking for?

Comment: There would be some better alternatives , but one of the last options to try will be to `cherry-pick` changes and add to release branch .